# Android Matcher.replaceAll/replaceFirst problem with groups count > 9

Tags: java, android, regex

I've found some problem with Matcher.replaceFirst/replaceAll when subgroup count in regex is more than 9...
simple example:

`String res = "abcdefghij".replaceFirst("(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)", "$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9 $10");`

Expected result is `"a b c d e f g h i j"` but got `"a b c d e f g h i a0"` string.

This problem can reproduced in Android runtime, but on local unit tests with desktop java it works well.
When I tried to debug it step by step, I've found following ugly code in Android sources of Matcher class:

```
private void appendEvaluated(StringBuffer buffer, String s) {
        boolean escape = false;
        boolean dollar = false;
        boolean escapeNamedGroup = false;
        int escapeNamedGroupStart = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if (c == '\\' && !escape) {
                escape = true;
            } else if (c == '$' && !escape) {
                dollar = true;
            } else if (c >= '0' && c <= '9' && dollar) { //<<<<------ WHAT IS IT?!
                buffer.append(group(c - '0'));
                dollar = false;
            } else if (c == '{' && dollar) {
                escapeNamedGroup = true;
                escapeNamedGroupStart = i;
            } else if (c == '}' && dollar && escapeNamedGroup) {
                String namedGroupName =
                    s.substring(escapeNamedGroupStart + 1, i);
                buffer.append(group(namedGroupName));
                dollar = false;
                escapeNamedGroup = false;
            } else if (c != '}' && dollar && escapeNamedGroup) {
                continue;
            } else {
                buffer.append(c);
                dollar = false;
                escape = false;
                escapeNamedGroup = false;
            }
        }

        if (escape) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("character to be escaped is missing");
        }

        if (dollar) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal group reference: group index is missing");
        }

        if (escapeNamedGroup) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Missing ending brace '}' from replacement string");
        }
    }
```

this is part of SDK API 29... I've checked API 30 level, it has same code.

maybe someone already solve this problem?
I think it needs to create custom replacer with more correct logic...